# C# Custom Login (With no use of Web.Config) (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I don't really like the idea of defining user required pages in the web.config, and defining the login page and such in web.config... My gut tells me that sort of logic should exist in the c# code.

So i am looking for a tutorial, or just some source code from something where a custom login system is made with custom database structure so that i can code all the login and user role logic my self, without using web.config at any point.

Then i can make my own custom attributes, and what ever i need.

Can someone help me out, i will be really grateful :)? My head is about to explode :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think default ASP.NET MVC application template (internet application) provides custom implementation of authentication.

It uses ASP.NET stuff like Membership and database schema though, but they should be fine example to follow.

Also you may find useful this question [ASP.NET MVC 3 User Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463852/asp-net-mvc-3-user-authentication)

Comment: But can you tell me if it is possible to avoid useing web.config and still be useing formAuthentication and membershipProvider?