# MVC3 User Authentication link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

In my application I have an administrator who can create `Tournament` objects. When the object is created the service also creates a user (based on the tournament director's info which was entered at creation). The username for the user is the director's e-mail, the password is randomly generated and then mailed to the director.

When the director logs on with his e-mail address and password, I need to be able to link him to his own tournament, in order to only allow him to edit his own tournament's details. I have tried to find a way to store the `TournamentId` in the default ASP Net Users database, but was unsuccessful.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237394/asp-net-mvc-3-using-authentication/4692843#4692843) SO question which would certainly help me, but I can't figure out how it would apply to my problem. When the user logs on, I can't put the `TournamentId` in the userdata seeing as I don't know it.

Should I then do a lookup in the `Tournament` table to see which ID corresponds to the email address entered at login and store that in the userData? It seems quite unelegant this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should have a CreatedBy column in your Tournament table where you store the ID of the user who created the tournament. Then when the user logged in, get his id ( may be from session ,if you store it there), Do a select query `where CreatedBy=loggedInUserId` .That should do the trick.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question slightly, but I think I know what to do now, thanks.